# Animation copied from the identical object gets messed up

Tags: animation, dopesheet, actions

Noob question... I have two animated, identical objects (**Object1** and **Object2**). They are copies of one object, imported as FBX in one Blender file. They have two different animations, one per each object (**animation1** and **animation2**) that look fine. I'd like to copy **animation2** from **Object2** to **Object1** and then to delete the **Object2**.

However, when I copy the animation, it gets messed up. **Object1** flies away, or gets weird rotation with the **animation2** selected, while its original **animation1** still works ok.

Link to the example blend file: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/14f0x8uB-ZktIS_--wYyZK7eEd61wY3Jh/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14f0x8uB-ZktIS_--wYyZK7eEd61wY3Jh/view)

I tried this:

- Selected both objects, Object1 first
- Object > Make Links > Animation Data

I also tried this:

- Selected **Object1**
- Dope Sheet > Action Editor >  Action browser: from the drop down list selected '**animation2**'

I also tried the 'Append' method:

- **Object1** selected
- File > Append > selected the blend file that contains object with **animation2** > Actions > selected **animation2**

In all cases it seems that bones are animated ok, but the **Object1** itself gets weird location/rotation, as if its origin point gets 'blown' away.

Can you help out?

Answer (score 1):

Your 2 armatures are not exactly the same, in *Object 1* the bone called *Bip001* is placed like that, which seems about correct:

[image]

Whereas in *Object 2* the same bone is placed like that, which seems incorrect (or at least it's not common):

[image]

So when you'll copy the action of *Object 2*, and if this action has some keyframes for this bone, you'll get an action that won't work correctly for *Object 1*. To fix that you either need, for *Object 1*, to copy *Object 2*'s armature (image below), even though the setting is weird, or first correct the keyframes in *Object 2*, then copy the action.

[image]

By the way to copy an action you can just select it in the dropdown panel in the *Dope Sheet* in *Action Editor* mode (no need for *Object > Make Links > Animation Data*):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, you're really sharp-eyed. I have no idea why this bone is off, maybe because model was exported from 3DSMax before importing to Blender. Anyway, unfortunately, fixing the bone position didn't solve the issue. If I make a correction to any of those objects (I tried both), then the corrected object acts strange on its own action, just like in the case of copying the action from other object. It seems that actions on these objects work only if Bip001 stands just as is, otherwise the animation gets corrupted. Thank you anyway, I'll try some different solution.

Comment: Sure, it will only work with the animation if you keep the bone at this position, so you either need to copy the exact same armature, or correct the bone position and then correct its keyframes